# Is this right way to call php file using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to call the php file onclick of button ,
i tried using ajax but many of them said not to use for downloading the file.

here is my code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
console.log("plugin script loaded3");
$('#csv').click(function()
{
 alert("csv");
 document.location.href = "/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/php/export_csv.php";

});
});
```

Even tried using **$get** but its not getting downloaded.

when i click the button it has to call php file which download csv format.

Comment: What's wrong with: `<a href='/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/php/export_csv.php'>click</a>`

Comment: @freedomn-m whats wrong with this??? i have not tried <a href=''></a>

Comment: @freedomn-m its perfectly working fine.But why its not coming to the above code.\

Comment: @JMR JavaScript to accomplish what a simple plain link could do is just needlessly complex

Comment: What's the *actual* problem?  That you can't download a file or that you don't get an event when you click a button?

Comment: Do you get "plugin script loaded3" in the console?  Do you get the alert("csv")?

Comment: yes , its getting loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your jquery startup to simply:

```
$(function() {
    $('#csv').click(function() {
        alert("csv");
    });
});
```

---

Alternatively, to download a "file", you can add it as the href to an anchor link, eg:

```
<a id='downloadlink' href='/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/php/export_csv.p‌​hp'>csv</a>
```

if you need to add parameters, you can change the href via jquery, eg:

```
$("#downloadlink")
    .prop("href", "/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/php/export_csv.p‌​hp?param1=" + param1value);
```

---

Alternatively (again), it could be that you are adding the "#csv" button dynamically, after jquery startup has run, in which case you need event delegation.  See this question for more info: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Glad to help, but interested in which bit fixed it for you (I can edit to remove the irrelevant part).

Comment: i used normal <a href></a>

Answer (score 2):

You can simply try this

```
<a href="/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/php/export_csv.php">Download</a>
```

Comment: i agree with your answer ..But what if i use button onclick function i need to know why its not coming.